# Google Maps API - Iterating markers, all have same content

Tags: javascript, maps

I've been piecing this code together over today, to display markers that are pulling from my XML file.

```
   function load() {
        var cluster = [];
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.848461, 174.763336),
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        downloadUrl('functions/toXml.php', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
                var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
                var price = markers[i].getAttribute("price");
                var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
                var html = "<b>" + markers[i].getAttribute("name") + "</b> <br/>" + markers[i].getAttribute("address");
                var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: point,
                    icon: icon.icon,
                    shadow: icon.shadow
                });
                marker.addListener('click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(html);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                     }
                })(marker, i));
          cluster.push(marker);
        }
        var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map,cluster,{imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
      });
    }
```

It is mostly working, however I think I've screwed up somewhere in the iterative process, as all of my info windows have the same (the last) name & address.

I've moved a few things around but can't quite figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through many iterations and rage quits, I've figured it out. Here is my code in case anyone else comes across this issue.

```
function initMap() {
     var cluster = [];
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.848461, 174.763336),
  zoom: 12
});
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
  downloadUrl('functions/toXml.php', function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;

    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
      var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
      var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
      var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
          parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

      var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
      var strong = document.createElement('strong');
      strong.textContent = name
      infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
      infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

      var text = document.createElement('text');
      text.textContent = address
      infowincontent.appendChild(text);
      var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        label: icon.label
      });
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
      cluster.push(marker);
    });
       var options = {
          imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
      };

    var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map,cluster,options);
  });
};
```